# Android: File Not Found Excpetion after crreating a file that is named the same as the original name of a renamed file

Tags: android

Here is the thing.

I've been fighting for weeks with horrible Android 11+ file permissions.

The entire purpose of my app is to create and maintain a single file. If you move the phone or device you copy (via whichever method you want) that file to the new phone or device to the exact same location and that is all the application needs.

So my file is maintained in Documents/MyWorkDir/data.aux

Here is the error:

1. I create the file. Add some information to it.
2. Close the app
3. Go to the Documents/MyWorkDir/data.aux and rename the file data2.aux
4. Open the app. Recreate the file. Add some other information to it.
5. Close the app.
6. Go to the Documents/MyWorkDir/ rename the newly created data.aux to data1.aux. Rename data2.aux to data.aux (should see the original information added in step 1).
7. Open the app and get the error:

   java.io.FileNotFoundException (file path) open failed: EACCES (Permission Denied)

The error occurs on me doing:

```
    try{
        DataInputStream fis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(dataFile));
         //// DO STUFF

    }
    catch(Exception e){

        System.err.println("Got the exception when decrypting: " + e.getMessage());

    }
```

Where datafile is the path to the data.aux file.

My app requests the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_VIDEO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Previously my app would fail on Step 4. When trying to create the NEW data.aux file AFTER deleting or renaming the original data.aux I would get the EXACT SAME ERROR of EACCES. The way that I solved this error is by running this piece of code whenever the app boots app:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R){
        File file = new File(FULL_PATH_DATA);
        String filePath = file.toString();
        String mimeType = null;
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context, new String[]{filePath}, new String[]{mimeType}, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                Aux.DbugCcrypt("Scan File Completed. Path: " + path);
                if (uri == null){
                    Aux.DbugCcrypt("File Does not exist");
                }
                else {
                    Aux.DbugCcrypt("Scan File Completed. Uri: " + uri.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

In the Code above FULL_PATH_DATA is the path to the data.aux.

Apparently refreshing some Media Database does allow the app to recognize that a file has been deleted but now if the file is replaced with another equally valid file (the purpose of the test described) then it does not work. So people who update the older version of the app to the new one are unable to access the information on the file. Thus the entire point of the app fails.

I'm at a loss. What else can I possibly do to read and write the file transparently?

All of these problems disappear if I could simply ask the MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORARE permission but Google says that I don't have the right justification to publish my app with that permission.

Comment: "So my file is maintained in Documents/MyWorkDir/data.aux" -- that is not a particularly good choice, given your objectives and given your decision to use filesystem APIs. `Documents/` and `Downloads/` are dumping grounds, and so Android has greatly restricted the use of those. "Go to the Documents/MyWorkDir/data.aux and rename the file data2.aux" -- I am assuming that you are doing this step (and step 6) in another app. Your app cannot read or write files created by another app in `Documents/` or `Downloads/`.

Comment: You could use a server for the cross-device aspect. Have it be the "system of record", and have the app maintain a local cache of that data (e.g., in `getExternalCacheDir()`). Or, you could use the Storage Access Framework, though you would need to distinguish between starting a new `aux` file (`ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT`) or opening an existing one (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`). In terms of `MediaScannerConnection`, especially if you go the Storage Access Framework route, you may not need it, as it may get covered automatically.

Comment: I don't want my application to have an internet connection. No sure the the server stuff is, but if that is what you are referring to, then this is not a useful choice. Using could be usefull, but it raises two questions. The first is that I don't want dialogs to ask the user where to save or load, I want the location to be fixed. And I also need to be able to store a file that is neither image, video or any specific format. Are these issues if I use SAF?

Comment: @CommonsWare The file is always created by the app, but yes, the renaming is done using a file explorer

Comment: You could delete your own file entry from the media store but not those of other apps or filemanagers.

Comment: @blackapps Could you maybe elaborate?

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE once to let the user choose the Documents/MyWorkDir directory. You then have full access to that directory and can do with any file what you want.

Comment: @blackapps Interesting. But how would I avoid having the user have the directory every single time they open the app?

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate. It's just a fact.

Comment: `Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE once` !!!! so one time only for the life time of your app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256007/discussion-between-aarelovich-and-blackapps).

Comment: "But how would I avoid having the user have the directory every single time they open the app?" -- take [persistable permission](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/27/scoped-storage-stories-durable-access.html)

Comment: @blackapps.  I made the user select the directory. Followed the instructions to make the permissions persisntent. Stored the URI for the directory in the shared preferences. Then I reloaded the app retrieved the URI, listed the files got the URI for the file that I want and created a File object and the canRead and canWrite is telling me false in both accounts. This is insane. Is there REALLY no other way to write and read a file even if externally replaced? It's very very hard to believe.

Comment: @blackapps. In case it wasn't clear i di used the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. So that I would only have to do it once. That is the URI that I stored and asked for persistent permissions.

Comment: If you got a nice uri from ACTION_,OPEN_,DOCUMENT_TREE than you will not use the File class anymore. Only DocumentFile and DocumentContracts. Also you do not need to request any permission using SAF.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77525552/android-11-after-trying-to-take-persistent-permissions-on-a-file-still-no-perm