# Android 11: After trying to take persistent permissions on a file, still no permissions to read or write

Tags: android

I want the user to select a file. I do so like this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, Aux.ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_CCRYPT_ONLY);
```

Then I do this on activity result.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        if (requestCode == Aux.ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE_SELECT_CCRYPT_ONLY){

            Uri dataFileUri = data.getData();

            Aux.DbugCcrypt("Storing the URI of the Work Directory In Shared Preferences: " + dataFileUri.toString());
            Aux.storeStringInSharedPreferences(this,Aux.SHARED_PREF_STRING_KEY,dataFileUri.toString());

            // And now we take persistent permission.
            ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
            cr.takePersistableUriPermission(dataFileUri, (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION));

        }
    }
    else {
        // TODO Handle.
        Aux.DbugCcrypt("On Activity Result was not OK.");
    }
}
```

So basically I store the URI String in Shared Prefernces and ask for persistent permission on the file.

I then close app. And open it up again.

And I do this:

```
    DbugCcrypt("Getting the Shared Preference URI");
    String dataAuxUriString = getStringInSharedPreferences(context,SHARED_PREF_STRING_KEY);
    if (!dataAuxUriString.isEmpty()){
        DbugCcrypt("Got the URI File. Testing Read/Write" );
        Uri dataAuxUri= Uri.parse(dataAuxUriString);
        File testFile = new File(dataAuxUri.getPath());
        if (testFile.isDirectory()){
            DbugCcrypt("Is a directory");
        }
        else {
            DbugCcrypt("Data Aux File URI. Can Read: " + testFile.canRead());
            DbugCcrypt("Data Aux File URI. Can Write: " + testFile.canWrite());
        }
    }
    else {
        DbugCcrypt("Data Aux URI String is empty");
    }
```

Which returns this print out (DBugCCrypt is just calling System.err.println("[STUF]" +  message) )

```
[CCRYPT_DBUG] Getting the Shared Preference URI
[CCRYPT_DBUG] Got the URI File. Testing Read/Write
[CCRYPT_DBUG] Data Aux File URI. Can Read: false
[CCRYPT_DBUG] Data Aux File URI. Can Write: false
```

So my question is, why have I not been able to get read/write permssion on the file between application executions?

Comment: You have permission to access the individual file returned to you via its Uri. You will never have `File` access to that Uri. Is there a reason you aren't just using the Uri directly?

Comment: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` Please remove that line. It serves nothing and confuses readers.

Comment: @blackapps You mean in the content resolver? Or when calling the app? at most it is there twice right? I should leave it only in one place?

Comment: No it is only once in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        File testFile = new File(dataAuxUri.getPath());
```

There is no requirement for the user to have chosen a file on the local filesystem, let alone one that you can read and write using filesystem APIs.

```
        if (testFile.isDirectory()){
```

`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` opens a document. It will never open a document tree (e.g., a directory on the local filesystem). For that, you would use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`.

To work with the `Uri` that you get back from your `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` request, you can use:

- `ContentResolver`, such as `openInputStream()` and `openOutputStream()`; and
- `DocumentFile`, via `DocumentFile.fromSingleUri()` (or `DocumentFile.fromTreeUri()` for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`), which gives you an API that resembles a subset of `File`

The use of the Storage Access Framework is covered in many places, such as these from me:

- [This blog post series](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/19/scoped-storage-stories-saf-basics.html)
- [This chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-content-001.html) of [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/)
- [This chapter](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore/pages/chap-t29-001.html) of [this other free book](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore/)

And there are countless more posts, books, courses, and the like.

Comment: Ahhh DocumentFile. Got it the The Example code that I was readin was using a DocumentFile and not a File. Thought it was the same thing. All I wanted to do was check for permissions. Thank you! Now I know I can move on.

Comment: Question. I want my app to exclusively use this as the file management system and not use what I used previously, what is the minimum android version that can use my app?

Comment: @aarelovich: `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` works back to Android 4.4. That is also [how far back the Jetpack libraries go](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2023/10/androidx-minsdkversion-19.html), for things like `DocumentFile`. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` was added in Android 5.1 IIRC.

Comment: I finally got it to work. Thank you so much. ONe final question If, I may. I'm unclear now on what permissions do I actually need. Right now I'm asking for read write external storage and read all types of media files (for Newer Androids), but this would bypass the need for those permissions right?

Comment: @aarelovich: Probably yes. I caveat with "probably" just because I don't know what else your app might be doing. If all you are using is the Storage Access Framework, you do not need any particular `<uses-permission>` elements.

Comment: Correct. All I do is maintain this file. Thank you!